# docker build fails when running cpanm

Tags: docker, perl, cpan, cpanm

In docker container I have a perl script and I need to be able to parse json I tried to have `CPAN JSON` installed for perl in my Dockerfile.

So I am doing the following in my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM centos:7.9.2009
RUN yum install -y cpanm \
      perl \
      perl-App-cpanminus \
      perl-Config-Tiny \
      sudo \
      &&  yum clean all \
      && sudo cpanm install JSON;
```

But when I do a `docker build` I get:

```
#0 41.76 Configuring Test-Simple-1.302195 ... OK
#0 41.95 Building and testing Test-Simple-1.302195 ... OK
#0 68.48 Successfully installed Test-Simple-1.302195
#0 68.59 Building and testing JSON-4.10 ... OK
#0 126.9 Successfully installed JSON-4.10
#0 127.0 2 distributions installed
------
ERROR: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yum install -y cpanm     perl     perl-App-cpanminus     perl-Config-Tiny     sudo     &&  yum clean all     && sudo cpanm install JSON;]: exit code: 1
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Note that `cpanm install JSON` will install `JSON` but also install a module called `install`! You probably just wanted `cpanm JSON`.

Comment: Tip: Installing JSON::XS will make JSON *much* faster (since JSON uses pure-Perl JSON::PP by default). That said, I recommend Cpan::JSON::XS over both of those.

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues you should fix.

1. The package `cpanm` is not available for installation in the 1st place.
   Run `docker run -it centos:7.9.2009 /bin/bash` and in the container do `yum install -y cpanm`.
   I got:

> No package cpanm available.
> Error: Nothing to do

When I ran `yum install -y cpanm perl sudo perl-App-cpanminus` and then `echo $?` the return was `0` as it did install the other packages. This means that this stage isn't what broke your build. That is because the package you need in order to install packages from `cpanm` is `perl-App-cpanminus`. To fix this, just remove `cpanm` from the list of modules to install (since you're already installing `perl-App-cpanminus`). As this didn't break the build it is not strictly necessary just highly recommended.

2. After that running the command `cpanm install JSON` returned:

```
[root@aabe6178c007 /]# cpanm install JSON
--> Working on install
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/D/DA/DAGOLDEN/install-0.01.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring install-0.01 ... OK
Building and testing install-0.01 ... FAIL
! Installing install failed. See /root/.cpanm/work/1692109504.103/build.log for details. Retry with --force to force install it.
--> Working on JSON
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/I/IS/ISHIGAKI/JSON-4.10.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring JSON-4.10 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Test::More
--> Working on Test::More
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/E/EX/EXODIST/Test-Simple-1.302195.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Test-Simple-1.302195 ... OK
Building and testing Test-Simple-1.302195 ... OK
Successfully installed Test-Simple-1.302195
Building and testing JSON-4.10 ... OK
Successfully installed JSON-4.10
2 distributions installed
[root@aabe6178c007 /]#
```

So as you can see you do not need the word `install` there. Running `echo $?` the return code was `1`, so this is the step that broke your build.

**Side notes**

- If you are running the container without changing your user inside it (we didn't see the `Dockerfile` so I can't tell) the package `sudo` is redundant.
- As you are still root while installing the packages using `sudo` in the command `&& sudo cpanm install JSON;` is certainly redundant.
- Apparently there's a dummy package called [install](https://metacpan.org/pod/install) in cpanm just for such an occasion.

Comment: So what do I need to remove then?

Comment: I guess I can not install `JSON`?

Comment: So how do I find such a repository and set it to my Dockerfile?

Comment: LMK if it works.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't answer your question, but I recently had to debug a cpanm situation by figuring out how to find the cpanm errors (although setting `--verbose` can work too). I wanted to grab the build log for a failed build.

First, find the container ID of whatever the build left behind. This is likely the most recent container, but also the command will have the start of the PERL_CARTON_MIRROR environment variable:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND     ...
2eae7f9e757a   9e2398121731             "cpanm …"   ...
```

Commit that container to an image by using the container ID (the first column):

```
$ docker commit 2eae7f9e757a
sha256:6887b59a7ed957c3ff38d0652929847a1ef200461e8f117c6a2746f066206b3f
```

Now grab the cpanm build log:

```
$ docker cp -L 6887b59a7ed9:/root/.cpanm/build.log build.log
```

Comment: Why did you need to do a `docker commit` and not just do a `docker run` directly and find the log?

Comment: If the build fails, there's nothing to run.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly `cpanm` is not a package in CentOS. I would recommend breaking the install steps into separate `RUN` commands just for the sake of maintaining the image (and seeing errors).

```
FROM centos:7.9.2009
RUN yum install -y perl sudo perl-App-cpanminus
RUN yum clean all
RUN cpanm install --notest JSON Config::Tiny
```

Secondly, there is no need to `sudo` `cpanm`. If you install `cpanm` I don't see why you'd want to install `Config::Tiny` via `yum`, so instead I would install it with `cpanm`.

Breaking these commands up reveal the actual error, being `cpanm` is not a package you can install on CentOS. It is: `perl-App-cpanminus` instead.